# Setear src de iframe desde JS / jQuery lanza DOMException:cross-origin

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Estoy intentando setear el valor del atributo src de un iframe (con una ruta relativa) con JS o jQuery y me lanza una DOMException. Si le seteo el valor del atributo src directamente en el HTML no me lanza dicha excepción, sólo cuando seteo el valor desde JS o jQuery. Al ser la misma aplicación y ver que sólo pasa al ponerlo dinámicamente por así decirlo, no le veo sentido a ese error y no consigo solucionarlo. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Aunque se lanza una excepción, funciona sin problemas y el iframe se rellena como toca, pero no sé el porqué de la excepción.

`VM45:21 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://localhost:8123" from accessing a cross-origin frame. at fix (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:21:8) at fix (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:23:5) at Object.dojo.html.getDocumentWindow (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:26:3) at Object.registerAllWindows (eval at dj_eval (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:108:33), <anonymous>:212:29) at Array.<anonymous> (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:259:9) at Object.dojo.hostenv.loaded (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:239:7) at Object.dojo.hostenv.callLoaded (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:295:14) at Object.dojo.hostenv.modulesLoaded (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:288:14) at dj_load_init (https://localhost:8123/sisvel/lib/dojo/dojo.js:851:14)`

Comment: Es un error de seguridad. Aqui la respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: @Mork Entendería el error de seguridad si estuviese intentando rellenar el iframe con información de otra página o dominio, pero el src que le pongo es una ruta relativa de una jsp de mi aplicación, mismo dominio, mismo puerto... además si le pongo el src directamente en el hmtl no lanza la excepción, sólo si se lo pongo con JS o jQuery...